# sqlite3 update statement in python returns lock error

Tags: python, sqlite, ipython

I am trying to update a sqlite3 database through iPython.
I can succesfully insert data into the database, but when I try to update a row it returns the following error on me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-6483798c376d> in <module>()
      2 conn.text_factory = str
      3 conn.execute("update series set html='test123' where url='https://www.google.com/'")
----> 4 conn.commit()
      5 print "Total number of rows updated :", conn.total_changes

OperationalError: database is locked
```

The python code I used is the following.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
conn.text_factory = str
conn.execute("update series set html='test123' where url='https://www.google.com/'")
conn.commit()
print "Total number of rows updated :", conn.total_changes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

And then I found out through

```
fuser mydb.db
```

on the command line that a previous python process had the db locked :(

sorry to keep you people busy with my RTFM stuff